# Laravel 5.4 and Datatables - Ajax - Saving / Posting Data - Server Side

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel, datatables, eloquent

I'm currently trying to save data from datatables back to the database. I'm working on form fields within the datatables and would like to change the input values and save back to the database. Ideally what I would like is to be able to save to another table in the database if the id doesnt already exist however for now I am only trying to make changes and get it back to the original table.
I'm using laravel 5.4 and datatables plugin.
I've been looking up various posts on laracasts, stack overflow and datatables. I've dd my data to be saved in my controller and keep getting an object in return. I've tried changing protected $casts in my model to see what values im getting in dev tools and it isnt helping. I've also tried multiple save methods in my controller with no avail. Please see below for response and code:

**screenshot 1**
[image]

**screenshot 2**
[image]

Routes:

```
Route::get('/plunker', ['uses'=>'Controller@plunker']);
Route::get('/plunker/ttotgetposts', ['as'=>'plunker.ttotgetposts','uses'=>'Controller@ttotGetPosts']);
Route::post('/plunker', 'Controller@saveOrUpdate')->name('saveOrUpdate');
```

Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \DB;

class Inducted extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string',
        'book_name' => 'string',
        'date_inducted' => 'string',
    ];
    protected $table = 'books';
    protected $fillable = ['book_id', 'book_name', 'date_inducted', 'updated_at', 'created_at'];

}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Save test</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-3.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery-ui.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/led.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ssstyle.css">
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui.accordion.multiple.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/demo.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h3>ttot Save Test</h3>
<div>
    <div class="containershe">
        <table id="books" class="ttotsave" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr><th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Inducted</th>
                {{--<th>Edit</th>--}}
                {{--<th>Delete</th>--}}
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" type="submit">Submit</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            oTable = $('#books').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "scrollY": "500px",
                "scrollX": true,
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging": true,
                "ajax": "{{ route('tabletotable.ttotgetposts') }}",
                "dataSrc" : "",
                "columns": [
                    {'data': 'id', render: function ( data, type, row)
                    {
                        if (data) {
                            var id = $('<div />').text(data).html();
                        }
                        else {
                            var id = '';
                        }

                        return '<input type="text" id="id" name="id[' + $('<div />').text(row.id).html() + ']" value=" ' + id + ' ">';
                    } },
                    {'data': 'book_name', render: function ( data, type, row)
                    {
                        if (data) {
                            var name = $('<div />').text(data).html();
                        }
                        else {
                            var name = '';
                        }

                        return '<input type="text" id="name" name="name[' + $('<div />').text(row.id).html() + ']" value=" ' + name + ' ">';
                    } },
                    {'data': 'date_inducted', render: function ( data, type, row)
                    {
                        if (data) {
                            var date = $('<div />').text(data).html();
                        }
                        else {
                            var date = '';
                        }

                        return '<input type="text" id="inducted" name="inducted[' + $('<div />').text(row.id).html() + ']" value=" ' + date + ' ">';
                    } },
                ]
            });


            $('button').click( function() {
                var data = oTable.$('input, select').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('button').data('token'),
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'tabletotable',


                    dataSrc : 'data',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: data,

                    async: 'false',


                    success: function()
                    {
                        alert('saved');
                        console.log('my message' + response + data);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Books;
use App\Inducted;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DataTables;
use DB;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function plunker()
    {
        return view('plunker');
    }

    public function ttotGetPosts()
    {
        $users = DB::table('books')->select('*');
        return DataTables::of($users)
            ->make(true);
    }

    public function saveOrUpdate(Request $request){
        dd($request->all());
        DB::table('books')->where('id','=', $request->get('id'))
            ->update(['book_name' => $request->get('name'),
                'date_inducted' => $request->get('inducted')]);
        return redirect('/index')->with('status','Successfully updated !');
    }
}
```

Any more info that you require just let me know

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public function saveOrUpdate(Request $request){
    // dd($request->all());
    $ids = $request->get('id');
    $names = $request->get('name');
    $inducteds = $request->get('inducted')

    foreach($ids as $id) {
        DB::table('books')->where('id','=', $id)
        ->update([
            'book_name' => $names[$id],
            'date_inducted' => $inducteds[$id]
        ]);
    }

    return redirect('/index')->with('status','Successfully updated !');
}
```

Comment: Damn.......your a bloody legend. I've been milling over this for days :)   I've only been developing for 4 months and still getting my head around things. Thanks Heaps